# Bootstrap - Make child elements horizontally aligned to middle within a col-lg-4 class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am with Bootstrap 4.3.1 and use flex for page layout.

```
<div class='row d-flex align-items-center'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <label class='col-form-label font-weight-bold display-6' for="inputDeploymentLocation">Deployment Location</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mr-lg-2" id="inputDeploymentLocation" name='inputDeploymentLocation'>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

The select element is currently horizontally top-aligned. How can I set the select element horizontally aligned in the middle of the column?

Answer (score 0):

**.row** in Bootstrap 4 have **display: flex** so we can remove the d-flex.  **.align-items-center** will only affect the direct children.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-lg-12'>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label class='col-form-label font-weight-bold display-6' for="inputDeploymentLocation">Deployment Location</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mr-lg-2" id="inputDeploymentLocation" name='inputDeploymentLocation'>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body class="all">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label class='col-form-label font-weight-bold display-6' for="inputDeploymentLocation">Deployment Location</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mr-lg-2" id="inputDeploymentLocation" name='inputDeploymentLocation'>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use `align-items-center` to the immediate parent `.row`
Hope it'll help.